# Woocommerce REST API - custom meta_data showing on admin product page as single letter?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, woocommerce-rest-api

I have an interesting problem that i'm not sure how to deal with. I'm trying to push meta data using the latest Woocommerce REST API. When i push from PHP to woo and print the result, i can see that it's clearly been added correctly.

```
[meta_data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 108536
                [key] => _product_size_guide
                [value] => thevalue
            )

    )
```

this is great, it does exactly what i want it to. However, if i go into the product using the WP Admin, i'm finding that the stored value is appearing as it's first letter. In this case, "t" and nothing else. It also displays as this on the public product page. It's a simple text field.

If i type over the "t" and hit save it stores that value correctly. Displaying on the front end as it should.

It looks like meta_data pushed from the REST API isn't being pulled out correctly by wordpress... so here i am asking what is causing me to pull my hair out?

I'm using the official woocommerce php wrapper.

My functions.php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {
  global $woocommerce, $post;
  echo '<div class="options_group">';
  ?>
    <p class="form-field custom_field_type">
        <label for="custom_field_type"><?php echo __( 'Product Size Guide', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <span class="wrap">
            <?php $custom_field_type = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_product_size_guide', true ); ?>  
            <input placeholder="<?php _e( 'URL to Size Guide', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" class="" type="text" name="_size_guide" value="<?php echo $custom_field_type[0]; ?>" style="width: 180px;" />
        </span>
        <span class="description"><?php _e( 'Image used for the size guide!', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
    </p>
  <?php
  echo '</div>';

}
 function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
    // Custom Field
    $custom_field_type =  array( esc_attr( $_POST['_size_guide'] ) );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_size_guide', $custom_field_type );

}

 //SUCCESSFULL WOOCOMMERCE SCIENCE
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    // Adds the new tab

    $tabs['size-gude'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Size Guide', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );

    return $tabs;

}
function woo_new_product_tab_content() {

    // The new tab content

    echo '<h2>Size guide for garment</h2>';
    $getSizeLink =get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_product_size_guide', true);
    if(empty($getSizeLink[0])){
    echo "No Size Guide Available.";
    }else{
    echo "<img src='" . $getSizeLink[0] . "' />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that i was being silly. The example i was working on used an array to store several different custom fields at once, and i was calling array point as opposed to just the array. eg:

```
$custom_field_type[0]
```

instead of just

```
$custom_field_type
```

Sorry for being a derp! I hope this helps other people who might be as silly as i am!